# ColdFusion: multiple form submit at once on a single page

Tags: forms, coldfusion

On a page, I have a ColdFusion loop that generate multiple forms and I want to submit them all. However, I realized only the first form is submitted since page reload afterward. Is there a way to submit them all?

```
    <cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#form.found#" >
      <cfif structKeyExists(form, "radioButton#i#")>
        <cfset selectedItem = #form["radioButton" & i ]#>
        <cfform id="createForm" name="createForm" method="post" action="/build/create_action.cfm">
          <input type="hidden" name="selectedItem" value="#selectedItem#"> 
        </cfform>
        
        <script>
          document.createForm.submit();
        </script>
      </cfif>
    </cfloop>
```

CreateForm will call the create_action process that will act on the selectedItem and eventually insert the result into the database. So I want to loop through all selectedItem and call the create_action process on each one of them.

Currently oldCreateForm takes in one selectedItem, passes it to create_action and processes it. I would like to change it so I can select multiple items, click submit and have create_action process all of them without changing create_action.

Comment: Can't you just wrap the variables in several different input tags and send it all along with just one post? Otherwise you'll need to make it with an ajax request.

Comment: Generally, the only reason you would have multiple forms is because you want the user to only submit one of them.   If you want the user to submit everything, then everything should be contained in one form.

Comment: One form with 10 fields vs. 10 forms with 1 field. Can you tell us what you're tying to accomplish? Also, please don't use `<cfform>`, it's just going to cause you pain in the long run.

Comment: Many issues here as outlined in the comments above.  However, one thing I noticed is that every form is ID'd as `createForm`.  This defeats the purpose of the ID since each form ID needs to be unique.  The rendered HTML will only recognize the first form it finds with that ID and all forms rendered will submit the first form on the page.  You will need to create a unique ID for each form.

Comment: createForm will call the create_action process that will act on the selectedItem and eventually insert the result into the database. So I want to loop through all selectedItem and call the create_action process on each one of them

Comment: What's the use case for submitting multiple forms on page load?  I'm sorry but I'm failing to see the purpose of what you're trying to accomplish.  Also, my previous comment is valid about needing a unique value whenever you ID an object in your HTML otherwise unexpected results will follow.

Comment: It sounds like you have one page that inserts multiple rows into a db. If that is the case, it is just one form. The form handler page takes care of the multiple inserts.

Comment: Agreed. Is the reason you think you need multiple forms because you're uncertain how to process the dynamic fields on the action page if they're all within one form?